# Selenium Drag and drop not working in Chrome or Firefox

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the Drag and drop code below to drag a picture in to a photofield. This works fine in InternetExplorer, but doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome.
I don't understand why not.

As you can see in the code below I've tried a lot of different ways to do the drag and drop, but none of them works. 
The main problem is that the target is not updated after releasing the image.
I see the drop happen but no update.

Does anyone have any idea why this is? I'm using C# and the latest Selenium driver 2.39, chrome driver 2.8.

```
public static void DoDragAndDrop(IWebDriver driver, string dragImageId, string dropFieldId)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drag and drop image '{0}' to the editor {1}..", dragImageId, dropFieldId);
        IWebElement dragElement = WebDriverExtensions.TryFindElement(By.Id(dragImageId));
        IWebElement dropElement = WebDriverExtensions.TryFindElement(By.Id(dropFieldId));

        if(dragElement == null)
            Console.WriteLine("dragElement is null");
        if(dropElement == null)
            Console.WriteLine("dropElement is null");

        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", dragElement);
        Thread.Sleep(500);

        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", dropElement);
        Thread.Sleep(200);

        Console.WriteLine("Drag and drop 1");
        var builder1 = new Actions(driver);
        builder1.MoveToElement(dragElement).ClickAndHold();
        builder1.MoveToElement(dropElement).Build().Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Console.WriteLine("Drag and drop 2");
        var builder2 = new Actions(driver);
        builder2.DragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement);
        Thread.Sleep(2000);

        Console.WriteLine("Drag and drop 3");
        var builder3 = new Actions(driver);
        builder3.DragAndDrop(dragElement, dropElement).Build().Perform();
        IAction dragAndDrop = builder3.ClickAndHold(dragElement)
            .MoveToElement(dropElement)
            .Release(dropElement)
            .Build();
        dragAndDrop.Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(2000);


        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Drag and drop succeeded..");
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I've got it working in FireFox now. Chrome still fails.
The only difference is that I've added offsets in the MoveToElement method, as seen in The Rookies comment.

```
var builder = new Actions(driver);
        builder.ClickAndHold(dragElement);
        builder.MoveToElement(dropElement, 5, 5);
        builder.Perform();
        Thread.Sleep(250);
        builder.Release(dropElement);
        builder.Perform();
```

Comment: This fixed it for me in Chrome v55.0.2. For some reason the element disappears now but it's at least dragging and dropping the element.

Comment: Once I removed the element from builder.release() everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Tried below sample code with chromedriver:2.15, chrome:v43 and is working fine as expected.

Sample Code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","drivers/chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver  driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    driver.get("http://jqueryui.com/droppable");

    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    WebElement dragElement = driver.findElement(By.id("draggable"));
    WebElement dropElement = driver.findElement(By.id("droppable"));
    Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
    builder.clickAndHold(dragElement).moveToElement(dropElement).release().build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

For firefox you can use following but it is in ruby

```
    panel = driver.find_element(:id, ' (panel around the picture)')
    target = panel.find_element(:xpath, ' ')
    source = panel.find_element(:xpath, ' ')
    driver.action.click_and_hold(source).move_to(target, 400, 150).release(target).perform
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

> ChromeDriver doesn't yet support the Actions commands. The Java
>   language binding translates the Actions requests into corresponding
>   mouse events before sending them to ChromeDriver, however there is no
>   guarantee the translated mouse events are completely equivalent to the
>   original Actions request.

Source: [Chromium bugtacker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=841#c80)